# Blank spaces in mysql_insert_id(); return

Tags: mysql, whitespace, mysql-insert-id

im getting blank spaces before my id?

when it comes back i get this?

```
&id=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201005
```

its supposed to just do this

```
&id=1005
```

Could it be my jquery data code?

```
    success: function(data) { 
    $('.success').slideDown('slow');  
    setTimeout(function(){window.location="user.php?v=single&id="+data;}, 3000);            
    }
```

or could it be the php code?

```
<?php
include 'includes/db.php';
protect();
if(isset(clean($_POST['uid']))) { 
$usrid=$_SESSION['uid'];
$insertNewUser=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (uid,status,datetime) VALUES  ('$usrid','0',NOW())") or die(mysql_error());
$id=mysql_insert_id();
echo $id;
$insertUserOptions=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_options (uid,lid) VALUES  ('$usrid','$id')") or die(mysql_error());
mkdir('media/listings/'.$id,0755);
mkdir('media/listings/'.$id.'/photos',0755);
mkdir('media/listings/'.$id.'/documents',0755);
mkdir('media/listings/'.$id.'/video',0755);
mkdir('media/listings/'.$id.'/audio',0755);
chmod('media/listings/'.$id,0775);
chmod('media/listings/'.$id.'/photos',0775);
chmod('media/listings/'.$id.'/documents',0775);
chmod('media/listings/'.$id.'/video',0775);
chmod('media/listings/'.$id.'/audio',0775);
} 
?>
```

UPDATE:

all the characters infront of the id were because i ad several lines of file includes in the protect() function. Once i moved those includes into a new function and called that accordingly it fixed the issue. Thanks martin for your clear solution as well :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, its not a solution but a workaround!

```
$('.success').slideDown('slow');  
    setTimeout(function(){window.location="user.php?v=single&id="+$.trim(data);}, 3000);            
}
```

It's uses the jQuery `trim` function to remove the spaces before and after. It should do the trick.

To actually ***fix*** it you can do a few other things:

**Option 1**

Return the ID as an json string, so the spaces are not visible.

**Option 2**

Check your files for echo spaces or maybe sometimes closing the php tag where it's not necessary and echo'ing spaces to your result.

Comment: That's an answer but doesn't solve the problem. He will hit this problem in future again. Why would you like to use workarounds to something that's easy to fix?

Comment: That's what i said in the first row, so no reason to downvote me.

Comment: @Ronn0 thanks for your knowledge. I am trying but to no avail. I havent yet tried the work around but this is something i have never hit before? How do i return the id as json string?

Comment: You can return it as a json string by: json_encode(array('id'=>$id)); But you need to change your jQuery script a bit too this way.

Comment: thats weird, i have tried everything and your work around works but why is it doing this? its almost like its creating 4 blank spaces which is the same amount of charcaters in the word data

Comment: It's hard to see it from here, i THINK there is some strange thing in the protect(); function, please check that one, pretty sure it's there.

Comment: found it! in the function. bummer! i must be tired.

Comment: Haha, sleep well in that case. And no problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably outputing some whitespaces in your code, for example in `includes/db.php`

My recommendation is to never close PHP code at the end of file. It's unnecessary and just makes troubles

Comment: I did not get your comment. My answer is actually a solution to a lot of problems

Comment: oh my bad, didnt mean to word my comment wrong sorry :). I meant i was checking my file structure in the php and so on to find where it it is actually causing this. Im removing close php tags on my process file and also on the include.

Comment: No, this is MY bad. I read "check your advice now". So, if it works, let me know

Comment: this is very weird, it worked great on my localhost install. And it seems this is the only bug. I have checked thorughly my include file for any extra spaces and i even tried it by removing all the extra stuff and ending the php with the echo id but still it returns the spaces?

Comment: when you incude a php file and then call a function directly under it - its only going to grab the php code from the function correct?

Comment: No. When you include file, it reads it and if there's some plain text it gets printed out